# Getting rid of the /Home path name in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I’ve only just started using ASP.NET MVC, and I have a somewhat trivial question: it seems that each controller has an attached folder-like path, so that my site becomes mydomain.net/Home/something. Is it possible to somehow get rid of the /Home part, so that the Home controller becomes ‘default’ for my web site and it’s possible to just use mydomain.net/something instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just define a route like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("{action}/{id}", new {controller="Home", action="Index", id=""});
```

The only problem is what about requests for your other controllers? For example, is

/Product/Foo

A request for HomeController.Product("Foo") or ProductController.Foo()?

You might need to use constraints to make the distinction clear.

Answer (score 1):

I did a blog post on a simple way to handle this.  I created a route constraint that selects a controller that you want to use for the root of your site.  [Here is the blog post if you're interested.](http://sonerdy.com/post/2011/01/15/getting-rid-of-home-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx)

Comment: The link returns a 404, NoSuchKey error. Maybe the answer could be edited and the details added here? Thanks!